# Display single service map for two serverless microservices instrumented with AWS Xray

Tags: java, node.js, graph, service, aws-xray

I have use-case where the Producer Java lambda publishes messages to SQS and Consumer Nodejs consumes them. Producer side of X-ray is enabled in serverless.yml; displays a Service map with all AWS components. The Consumer side of Nodejs lambda; is enabled with tracing. Now the problem is Aws Xray shows two service maps. I need to show a single service map. How to achieve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this question. Unfortunately this is *not* yet supported. Please see this open issue on the X-Ray Node JS SDK which explains why this is a difficult problem to solve:

https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/208